# SQL: how to remove duplicates when doing complex order by

Tags: sql, postgresql-15

Consider the following query:

```
SELECT u.id 
FROM users u
INNER JOIN users_game_level l ON l.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN l.level = 'BEGINNER' AND l.game_code = 'arcade' THEN 1
        WHEN l.level = 'MEDIUM' l.game_code = 'race' THEN 2
        WHEN l.level = 'PROF' THEN 3
    END ASC,
    u.last_online_at DESC,
    u.id DESC
LIMIT 100
```

`users` is related to `users_game_level` based on `one-to-many` relationship.

Basically I need all the users in an order, depending on some conditions from the second table.

But I get this error :

> ERROR: column "l.level" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

The same error goes for `l.game_code` and `u.last_online_at`. And if I add all these to the GROUP BY it returns duplicates nevertheless.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well a given user may have multiple levels.  _Which_ level should be used for ordering?

Comment: Joins do produce multiple rows for the driving tables. That's how they work. It seems you want to filter out some rows. Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: `order by` happens after everything else is done. At the point that `order by` runs, there is no column `l.level`. You merely have the aggregate result set with `u.id` to work with. Perhaps you want to order by the `max(l.level)` that the user might belong to? Think about which of the competing `l.level` values for any particular user that would cause the user to be ranked the way you wish, and use the appropriate aggregate formula to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A given user, by definition, may have multiple levels.  Hence, it makes no sense to be ordering by a single level, as it isn't clear *which* of several level values should be used.  Assuming you wanted to order by the *highest* level achieved, you could try:

```sql
SELECT u.id
FROM users u
INNER JOIN users_game_level l ON l.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY
    MAX(CASE WHEN l.level = 'BEGINNER' AND l.game_code = 'arcade' THEN 1
             WHEN l.level = 'MEDIUM' l.game_code = 'race' THEN 2
             WHEN l.level = 'PROF' THEN 3 END),
    u.id DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the calculation in a CTE and the query that CTE and removing the column you do not want in your result set

```
WITH _CTE AS (
    SELECT u.id,
    CASE
        WHEN l.level = 'BEGINNER' AND l.game_code = 'arcade' THEN 1
        WHEN l.level = 'MEDIUM' l.game_code = 'race' THEN 2
        WHEN l.level = 'PROF' THEN 3
    END OrderID,
    u.last_online_at
FROM users u
INNER JOIN users_game_level l ON l.user_id = u.id
)
Select id
from _CTE
GROUP BY u.id
order by OrderID ASC,last_online_at DESC, id DESC
```

Comment: Your query, after compiling the CTE, is almost identical to the OP's original query, and would yield the same error.